# How to import a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have my data in a separate file (same path as all other files). I am struggling with importing the JSON file. This is what I tried which did not work:

```
$.getJSON("rezepte.json", function(obj) {
var rezepte = obj.rezepte;
});
```

***update - this is what fianlly worked*** Thanks a lot for all your help.

```
var rezepte = $.getJSON("rezepte.json", function(obj) {
rezepte = obj.rezepte;
});
```

When using this data in the code direcly, all works well:

```
var rezepte = [
{ "name" : "Eierkopf" , "zutaten" : ["eier", "butter", "kekse"] , "menge" : ["3 Eier", "20g Butter", "5 Kekse"] , "portionen" : 1 , "zubereitung" : ["1. alles", "2. schön", "3. mischen."] },
{ "name" : "Käseschnitte" , "zutaten" : ["käse", "brot"] , "menge" : ["500g Käse", "2 Scheiben geschnittenes Brot"] , "portionen" : 2 , "zubereitung" : ["1. Brotunterseite mit Butter bestreichen (altes Brot verwenden)", "2. Brotoberseite mit Weisswein beträufeln", "3. mit Käse bedecken und würzen", "4. 20min. in vorgeheizten Ofen bei 180 Grad" , "5. nomal öpis"] },
{ "name" : "Gemüse-Auflauf" , "zutaten" : ["lauch"] , "menge" : ["1 Stengel Lauch", "5 Zitronen"], "portionen" : 4 , "zubereitung" : ["1. schneiden", "2. Kochen", "3. essen", "4. xxx", "5. yyy", "6. en guete"] } ];
```

Saved this as `rezepte.json`:

```
{
"rezepte" :

[
{ "name" : "Eierkopf" , "zutaten" : ["eier", "butter", "kekse"] , "menge" : ["3 Eier", "20g Butter", "5 Kekse"] , "portionen" : 1 , "zubereitung" : ["1. alles", "2. schön", "3. mischen."] },
{ "name" : "Käseschnitte" , "zutaten" : ["käse", "brot"] , "menge" : ["500g Käse", "2 Scheiben geschnittenes Brot"] , "portionen" : 2 , "zubereitung" : ["1. Brotunterseite mit Butter bestreichen (altes Brot verwenden)", "2. Brotoberseite mit Weisswein beträufeln", "3. mit Käse bedecken und würzen", "4. 20min. in vorgeheizten Ofen bei 180 Grad" , "5. nomal öpis"] },
{ "name" : "Gemüse-Auflauf" , "zutaten" : ["lauch"] , "menge" : ["1 Stengel Lauch", "5 Zitronen"], "portionen" : 4 , "zubereitung" : ["1. schneiden", "2. Kochen", "3. essen", "4. xxx", "5. yyy", "6. en guete"] }
]

}
```

***unfortunately it still does not work - the $.getJSON results in an array of 3 empty objects only*** Would be happy to get further help. Thx, Andi

Comment: You need to save your json file in `UTF-8` encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to access the `rezepte` property of the returned object.

```
$.getJSON("rezepte.json", function(obj) {
    var rezepte = obj.rezepte;
});
```

It wouldn't be wise to name that argument as `json`, as it's not, it's a JavaScript object (generally).

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. Your reply was leading me to the solution. Strange thing was that I had to declare the "var rezepte" first to get it work (see update above).

Answer (score 0):

You encoded it wrongly because of non-ascii symbols, `rezepte.json` should look like:

```
[{"name":"Eierkopf","zutaten":["eier","butter","kekse"],"menge":["3 Eier","20g Butter","5 Kekse"],"zubereitung":["1. alles","2. sch\u00f6n","3. mischen."]},{"name":"K\u00e4seschnitte","zutaten":["k\u00e4se","brot"],"menge":["500g K\u00e4se","2 Scheiben Brot"],"zubereitung":["1. Brotunterseite mit Butter bestreichen (altes Brot verwenden)","2. Brotoberseite mit Weisswein betr\u00e4ufeln","3. mit K\u00e4se bedecken und w\u00fcrzen","4. 20min. in vorgeheizten Ofen bei 180 Grad"]},{"name":"Gem\u00fcse-Auflauf","zutaten":["lauch"],"menge":["1 Stengel Lauch","5 Zitronen"],"zubereitung":["1. schneiden","2. Kochen","3. essen","4. xxx","5. yyy","6. en guete"]}]
```

Formated:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Eierkopf",
    "zutaten": [
      "eier",
      "butter",
      "kekse"
    ],
    "menge": [
      "3 Eier",
      "20g Butter",
      "5 Kekse"
    ],
    "zubereitung": [
      "1. alles",
      "2. sch\u00f6n",
      "3. mischen."
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "K\u00e4seschnitte",
    "zutaten": [
      "k\u00e4se",
      "brot"
    ],
    "menge": [
      "500g K\u00e4se",
      "2 Scheiben Brot"
    ],
    "zubereitung": [
      "1. Brotunterseite mit Butter bestreichen (altes Brot verwenden)",
      "2. Brotoberseite mit Weisswein betr\u00e4ufeln",
      "3. mit K\u00e4se bedecken und w\u00fcrzen",
      "4. 20min. in vorgeheizten Ofen bei 180 Grad"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Gem\u00fcse-Auflauf",
    "zutaten": [
      "lauch"
    ],
    "menge": [
      "1 Stengel Lauch",
      "5 Zitronen"
    ],
    "zubereitung": [
      "1. schneiden",
      "2. Kochen",
      "3. essen",
      "4. xxx",
      "5. yyy",
      "6. en guete"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. May I ask you to have look at the updated question. Is there something wrong in the format?

Comment: Compare how German symbols are encoded in your and in my version